# How to get child elements that is not deleted using nuxeo rest endpoint?

Tags: rest, nuxeo

When I call `http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/id/bad6cbc5-b75f-4373-981f-6908cec66779?enrichers.document=children` endpoint it returns all child elements include deleted elements. But I need to get only active elements and I think I should add isTrashed=false query to endpoint. But `http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/id/bad6cbc5-b75f-4373-981f-6908cec66779?enrichers.document=children&isTrashed=false` does not any effect. How can I get only active child elemets from nuxeo server using rest api?

Answer (score 0):

*/nuxeo/api/v1/id* endpoint with **children** enricher does not support this kind of filtering.

I see two options:

1. Implement own enricher which will support filtering of trashed documents. **children** enricher is implemented by `org.nuxeo.ecm.core.io.marshallers.json.enrichers.ChildrenJsonEnricher` class so you can inspire there how to do that.
2. Use different end point with page provider which supports filtering of trashed documents:
   `/nuxeo/api/v1/search/pp/advanced_document_content/execute?&ecm_parentId=bad6cbc5-b75f-4373-981f-6908cec66779&ecm_trashed=false`

Benefits of the second option:

- **paging** - simply add `currentPageIndex=0&offset=0&pageSize=20` to the query
- **properties** - you can define what properties do you need by adding of header: `properties:dublincore,common,uid,file`
- **enrichers** - it means that you can use enrichers for each child and receive for example permission or thumbnail URL for each child. To do that add this header: `enrichers-document: thumbnail, permissions`

Example curl call:

```
curl -X GET -u Administrator:Administrator \
 -H "properties:dublincore,common,uid,file" \
 -H "enrichers-document: thumbnail, permissions" \
 "http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/search/pp/advanced_document_content/execute?&ecm_parentId=bad6cbc5-b75f-4373-981f-6908cec66779&ecm_trashed=false" | jq
```

Comment: I change endpoint to http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/id/bad6cbc5-b75f-4373-981f-6908cec66779?ecm_trashed=false&enrichers.document=children, but it does not any effect

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that you are using _/nuxeo/api/v1/id_ endpoint and not _nuxeo/api/v1/search/pp_. I updated the answer with correct information which can help you - I hope.